# Медленно стартует Visual Studio. Можно ускорить?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

В общем, на работе и дома стоит `Visual Studio 2017` с одними и теми же плагинами, например ReSharper, но на работе она быстро стартует, чем дома, хотя дома у комп по мощнее:

Дома стоит Core I7 3770K vs рабочий Core I5 1 или 2 поколения.

Дома Windows 10 vs на работе Windows 7

Дома частота 8 ГБ 2333 vs рабочая 8 ГБ 1333

Диски дома и на работе стандартные HDD с той лишь разницей, что дома у меня 1 ТБ, а на работе 500 ГБ.

Вроде бы, если дома VS должна стартовать не быстрее, то хотя бы не хуже.

По факту при запуске график HDD уходит в потолок и VS запускается минут 10.

Куда копать?

Comment: Копать в сторону SSD. Ну или попробуй на чистой системе запустить. Хотя ssd лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 минут на старт это какое-то безумие. У меня VS 2008 запускается 3 секунды, а VS 2017 запускается за 6-7 секунд, от момента даблклика на иконке до полного открытия всех вкладок с исходниками большого проекта. Древний 6-ядерный Феном с 16гб памяти, но диск при этом 512гб SSD на котором все - система, студия, все проекты.

Так что ставьте SSD и забудьте все это как страшный сон.

Comment: Ну на работе на HDD по более шустро запускается.

Comment: Может, проблема в домашнем HDD?

Comment: @iluxa1810, причин может быть миллион. Например, диск на работе 7200об, а у вас 5400. И вообще диски разные бывают, и на таком количестве операций в/в это заметно сказывается.

Comment: ЛоЛ, оказывается у меня мои HDD , которые поддерживали SATA3 были подключены к SATA2 интерфейсу.

Comment: @iluxa1810, вряд ли это как-то влияло, даже для SSD разница между интерфейсами SATA2 и SATA3 заметна только на синтетических тестах. Скорее всего у вас просто диск медленнее. Вы посмотрите какие модели HDD, тогда можно будет объективно сравнить.

Comment: Переключение интерфейса решило проблему?

Comment: @Bakhuss чуть шустрее стало

Comment: @freim, 7200 так же.

Comment: @iluxa1810, 7200 диски бывают очень разные по скорости, нужно модели смотреть. А насчет переключения интерфейса - очень сомневаюсь, что вы это заметили. HDD даже близко не может полностью загрузить SATA2. Это может сделать только SSD, причем на конкретном тесте последовательного чтения больших блоков. В реальных задачах даже с SSD разница между версиями SATA глазу незаметна.

Comment: @freim ну... может это плацебо и мне кажется. Но, вроде, шустрее стало.